# Apply filter / mask in CSS?

Tags: html, css, text, layout

Anticipated Result:
[image: anticipated result]

What I managed to get:
[image: reality]

Please try not to give me absolute values, so that it's responsive. The Text and the background divider should be always at the center. The text should change its color as needed depending on each character's location.
Thanks in advance!

My Html Code:

```
<div class="bg"></div>
<header>Plants</header>
<h1>Fresh Plants <br> for You.</h1>
```

My CSS:

```
header {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.bg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(31,171,137,1) 0%, rgba(31,171,137,1) 50%, rgba(157,243,196,1) 50%, rgba(157,243,196,1) 100%);
    height: 52rem;
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
        font-size: 5rem;
        /*color: white;*/
        margin-left: 30.2rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        background-clip: text;
        -webkit-background-clip: text;
        color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
        /*background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(31,171,137,1) 0%, rgba(31,171,137,1) 50%, rgba(157,243,196,1) 50%, rgba(157,243,196,1) 100%);*/
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it's a `90deg` direction make both backgrounds `fixed` so they both consider the sreen as reference:

```css
header {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.bg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(31, 171, 137, 1) 50%, rgba(157, 243, 196, 1) 0) fixed;
  height: 52rem;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-align:center;
  color: #0000;
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 50%, blue 0) fixed;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg"></div>
<header>Plants</header>
<h1>Fresh Plants <br> for You.</h1>
```